# VB Owin Get Method Keyword issue

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, owin

I'm writing the below in VB.net for an Owin Controller. i'm trying to write the code for the GET Method and i get a Keyword can't be used as an identifier. How do i create a Get web method?

```
Public Class FactoryStatusController
    Inherits ApiController
Public Function Get() As String
    Return "TEst"
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use verbs like "get" or "put" or something that your programming language might confuse with something else. By default the system will take your request as a HttpGet. There is many others you can use. I suggest you search for Action selectors and Action verbs for mvc 5 or which ever version you have

Get method

```
 ' GET: /Account/Login
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Function Login(returnUrl As String, id As String) As ActionResult
        ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl
    End Function
```

Post method

```
    ' POST: /Account/Login

    <HttpPost>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
    Public Async Function Login(model As LoginViewModel, returnUrl As String, id As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
```

Comment: @SteveShort no problem bud